# Apache mod_rewrite RewriteCond to avoid loops

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What's the difference between:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

and this one:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^.
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

It happened that this last one used to work just fine for a long time, until suddenly it stopped working causing Apache to show the directory listing! The first one solved the issue.
So what's wrong with the second one?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
```

Checks whether REDIRECT_STATUS environment variable is equal to 200 (in fact, the pattern  will match any string containing 200).

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^.
```

Checks whether REDIRECT_STATUS environment variable is at least one character long.

The second one should work since 200 should match `^.`. Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Got any idea why using 200 avoids Apache from going crazy?

Comment: The rules you posted do not provide enough information. May be checking for 200 _is_ the right thing to do.

Comment: Ok will try to post complete rules

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121297/apache-mod-rewrite-redirect-status-condition-causing-directory-listing